# Javascript calculate totals within the object and sort by total

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to create a function that will take an object of student exam scores and calculate the total scores for all subjects for each student, then sort the students in the object based on their total_score.

Below is the before mapping and sorting, and the expected result.

```
const studentsExamScore = [
  {
    name: "Patty Colon",
    roll: "1001",
    subjects: [
      {
        name: "Match",
        score: 76,
      },
      {
        name: "Physics",
        score: 84,
      },
      {
        name: "Chemistry",
        score: 82,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Fredrick Hubbard",
    roll: "1002",
    subjects: [
      {
        name: "Match",
        score: 86,
      },
      {
        name: "Physics",
        score: 88,
      },
      {
        name: "Chemistry",
        score: 67,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Deanna Hogan",
    roll: "1003",
    subjects: [
      {
        name: "Match",
        score: 77,
      },
      {
        name: "Physics",
        score: 75,
      },
      {
        name: "Chemistry",
        score: 94,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**Expected Output**

The total_score is added to each student and they are sorted by their total score.

```
const ExpectedStudentListOutput = [
  {
    name: "Patty Colon",
    roll: "1001",
    total_score: 242,
    subjects: [
      {
        name: "Match",
        score: 76,
      },
      {
        name: "Physics",
        score: 84,
      },
      {
        name: "Chemistry",
        score: 82,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Fredrick Hubbard",
    roll: "1002",
    total_score: 241,
    subjects: [
      {
        name: "Match",
        score: 86,
      },
      {
        name: "Physics",
        score: 88,
      },
      {
        name: "Chemistry",
        score: 67,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Carrie Schneider",
    roll: "1004",
    total_score: 236,
    subjects: [
      {
        name: "Match",
        score: 88,
      },
      {
        name: "Physics",
        score: 83,
      },
      {
        name: "Chemistry",
        score: 65,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Loop through each user object and then loop through each subject and sum the scores. Seems straight-forward. What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: can u give me the solution of this problem ?

Comment: I just gave that. Do you not know how loops work in javascript? This is not a free code writing service. This site is for fixing issues with your existing code.

Comment: I was wrong, this is a free code writing service. You have an answer.

Comment: I added some clarity to your question, this is now a free question and code writing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const studentsExamScore = [
    {
        name: "Patty Colon",
        roll: "1001",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "Match",
                score: 76,
            },
            {
                name: "Physics",
                score: 84,
            },
            {
                name: "Chemistry",
                score: 82,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: "Fredrick Hubbard",
        roll: "1002",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "Match",
                score: 86,
            },
            {
                name: "Physics",
                score: 88,
            },
            {
                name: "Chemistry",
                score: 67,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: "Deanna Hogan",
        roll: "1003",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "Match",
                score: 77,
            },
            {
                name: "Physics",
                score: 75,
            },
            {
                name: "Chemistry",
                score: 94,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: "Carrie Schneider",
        roll: "1004",
        subjects: [
            {
                name: "Match",
                score: 88,
            },
            {
                name: "Physics",
                score: 83,
            },
            {
                name: "Chemistry",
                score: 65,
            },
        ],
    },
];

const addTotalScore = (data) => {
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.total_score = d.subjects.reduce((p, c) => p += c.score, 0);
    });
    data.sort((a, b) => b.total_score - a.total_score);

    return data;
}

console.log(addTotalScore(studentsExamScore));
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing to use array.map and sorting

```
function addTotalScore(studentsExamScore) {
   studentsExamScore.map((student) => {
    let totalScore = 0;
    student.subjects.map((subject) => {
      totalScore += subject.score;
    });
    student.total_score = totalScore;
  });
  studentsExamScore.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.total_score - a.total_score;
  });
  return studentsExamScore;
}
```

Comment: This solution *mutates* the variable `studentsExamScore`. You could use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new variable with `total_score` property on each element. You may want to avoid mutations. To sort the data you could use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @c0m1t thank you for that, i've changed the answer in-case this gets re-visited even though it's closed